# wrong output in arff

Tags: python, arff

I am using a Python script and writing the results (calculated using ntlk) to an arff file. The information that needs to go into the arff file is letters and words (nothing numerical). However, whenever I run my script I get an arff file containing zeros.. like this:

```
0,0.0,0.0,0
```

This is the piece of my code that writes to the arff:

```
     for fileid in corpus.fileids():
         cat = str(fileid.split('/')[0])
         text = corpus.words(fileid)
         text2 = corpus.raw(fileid)
         text3 = ngrams(text2, 3)
         text4 = ngrams(text2, 4)
         lijst = [frequencycount(text, freq)] + [frequencycount(text3, chartrigramfreq)]  + [frequencycount(text4, chartetragramfreq)]
         merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lijst)) 
         merged2 = ','.join(merged)
         filet.write("%s\n" % merged2)
         counter += 1
    print counter, fileid, time()-tijd
    filet.close()
```

Comment: Could you fix the indenting so it displays the way you see it in your script?

Comment: @brionius This should be better I think!

Comment: This code will print whatever frequencycount() returns, if that function returns a number, then that will be what is printed.

Comment: @JohnDoe much better.  Could you show the output of your script (the stdout - what it prints to the command line)?  It would also be helpful if you could have it `print text, text2, text3, merged2` right before the `filet.write` statement and post the output.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all answers! I just found the problem! :)

Comment: @JohnDoe : Would you mind posting it as an answer so anyone having a problem similar to yours can hopefully see what path you followed? :)

Comment: You are writing in ARFF format manually. Why you didn't use ARFF packages written for python. I used `LIAC-ARFF`, easy to read an write and change.